# C++ Visual Studio 2022 template SFINAE compile error after upgrade to latest version

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae

My code fails to compile in Visual Studio 2022 after an upgrade, but not on any other compiler that I tested (MacOS Clang, Linux GCC).

I was able to track this down to a very simple example. The following code fails only if the constant **test** is 0.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

template<std::enable_if_t<true>* = nullptr> void foo() {}
template<uint32_t, std::enable_if_t<true>* = nullptr> void foo() {}

int main()
{
    constexpr uint32_t test = 0;
    return foo<test>();
}
```

The error message is:

```
error C2668: 'foo': ambiguous call to overloaded function
message : could be 'void foo<0,0x0>(void)'
message : or       'void foo<0>(void)'
message : while trying to match the argument list '()'
```

Apparently VS is able to substitute my uint32_t for void* if the uint32_t is 0. After I figured that it only happens for the value 0, I tested something else:

```
void* x = 0; // this is fine for VS22
void* y = 1; // but this is an error
```

Is this a VS2022 compiler bug that I should report?

Assignment of an uint32_t to a void* shouldn't depend on its value or did I miss anything?
What does the standard say here?

Comment: FWIW : I tried on Version 17.2.5 , VisualStudio.17.Release/17.2.5+32616.157.  and your example compiles there.

Comment: What happens if you replace `constexpr` with `const`.  Looks like MSVC is treating your `constexpr` variable like a literal here.

Comment: I have the latest VS2022 (from last week) and it compiles here too. Perhaps we have some different options set?

Comment: @BoP I compile the code as C++17

Comment: @PaulSanders it needs to be constexpr to be able to use it as a template parameter.

Comment: See the linked post, it was discussed before. Only an integer literal of 0 is a valid void*, but since C++14, a constant expression is not. As I do not use a literal as template parameter but a constant expression, its a VS2022 bug

Comment: So it is the options.  :-) For me it compiles in C++17 mode if I also add the `/permissive-` option to get stricter. Or use C++20.

Comment: _it needs to be constexpr to be able to use it as a template parameter_ Good point, I'll go and stand in the corner.